# Is there a way to hook up my IPhone to my Windows computer to make and recieve calls and texts?

Tags: applications, iphone, windows

Basically what I am looking for is something similar to Phone Amego from [these](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16099/is-there-a-way-to-pickup-iphone-calls-on-my-macbook-pro) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/16119/64881), but for Windows. Also my desktop doesn't have Bluetooth so a solution that works over WiFi or by plugging my phone into the sync/charging cable would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Without a jailbreak, what you ask is not possible (Even on Mac OS).

Comment: Are there any apps exclusive to jailbroken phones that can accomplish this?